# Javascript code does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

In the image click I write code for invoke java like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>New Page 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="311">
            <tr>
                <td height="14">
                    <img onclick ="SignIn();" border="0" src="../images/Sign_In.gif" width="80" height="28">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            function SignIn(){
                alert();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code is working fine in Internet Explorer, but not in FireFox. What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you code post the HTML code as well.

Comment: 5 edits and not a single one correcting "Internet Explore"...

Comment: alert() also not working

Comment: Oi.. <img onclick='javascript: SignIn();'>, put your Javascript in the HEAD

Comment: The real problem is that Firefox needs an argument to alert. I've had this problem before. (and yes I've upvoted the correct answer :) )

Comment: PS you should really get Firebug to debug these kinds of errors in Firefox. Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Please read these - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
{ alert(); document.getElementById('FormSignIn').submit(); }
```

Documentation: [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

Comment: Right.. I make an assumption based on the limited info.. Indeed.

Comment: Oi.. <img onclick='javascript: myfunction("thisImageId");'>, put your Javascript in the HEAD

Comment: i try with this code ,
this code is working
but alert not working

<html>
<head>
<title>getElementById example</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor(newColor)
{
 elem = document.getElementById("para1");
 elem.style.color = newColor;
 alert();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="para1">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Since this question has completely changed, I shall bow out.  I believe [Chetan] has the solution.  Ask yourself.. What am I trying to ALERT(?)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an argument to alert. Seems firefox doesn't like it when you don't while IE shows a blank alert.

```
alert("text here");
```

Comment: hi tks,  this is  working.
But i try to pass value to the document, document.getElementById("para1").innerText="text here"; 
this is not working

Comment: innerText isn't supported by Firefox. Use innerHTML.

Comment: in each element in firefox we use "ID"? to passing and retrive values, as like xhtml?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exemple of what you should always do when validating web forms with javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>New Page 1</title>
    <!-- Inline javacript should be always inside header tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SignIn(){
        alert("");//In firefox you have to pass something to alert to make it work


        //More code logic you can put here

        //...
        //If everything is ok return TRUE to
        //post data to "somepage.aspx" if
        // dont return FALSE and do nothin
        if(everythingIsOk);
            return true;
        else
            return false;   
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="somepage.aspx">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="311">
                <tr>
                    <td height="14">
                        <input type="image" src="../images/Sign_In.gif" width="80" height="28" onclick="return SignIn();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("para1").value="text here"; this command is also not working, why?

Comment: in each element in firefox we use "ID"? to passing and retrive values, as like xhtml?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem now.
Fixed by cleaning cache in firefox : 
**Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Offline Storage (Cache): "Clear Now"**